# How to make cascade to false for all grails domains at global level

Tags: grails-orm, cascade, grails3

How to make cascade to false for all grails domains at global level.

Also i would like to have the option to set it on specific save operation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question:

> How to make cascade to false for all grails domains at global level.

It's a bit of an undocumented feature, but in your `application.groovy` file you can add

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    '*' cascade:'none'
}
```

Be aware that cascade validation will be disabled even if you use `validate(deepValidate:true)`.

**Note:** Even with cascade validation disabled, if you validate manually a nested instance before the outer instance, then the validation of the outer instance will collect the errors of the nested instance. This caused me a fair amount of confusion.

I have only tested this in Grails 3.3, I'm not sure if it works in other versions.